# Can I get around "There are multiple root elements"?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm working with a database that I have no control over, one column is an XML type, and it contains, yep, multiple root elements. So my LINQ throws an exception.

I understand the error and why, but I can't control the data. I'd rather not tweak any auto-generated code.

Is there any way to get around this exception?

Comment: It might depend on how you want to access the information.  Do you have example code you can share?

Comment: Well, it's not much, just a dataContext.MyTable.ToList() or similar. And I was intending to just pass some MyTable objects around.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subselect to add a root element younr xml-string:

```
select concat("<mynewroot>",mxmlcolumn,"</mynewroot>") from 
   (select * from mytable);
```

I know this is sql syntax and no linq-syntax but this should also be possible in linq, I hoep you get the idea.

An other way would be to not let linq interpret the xml column as xml but as string, or let it interpret the xml just as xml-fragment.

Comment: Combine that SQL statement with LINQ To SQL's method for executing ad-hoc SQL statement: `DataContext.ExecuteQuery()`. This will return an `IQueryable<T>`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx

Comment: p. campbell: That's a good idea, no doubt. Still I lose the convenient foreign key relationships that the dbml provides. I guess I could wire that up in the partial class. Intersting that sql server allows non-valid xml in an xml column, yet linq2sql doesn't support.